# swipe screen and joystick zone

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile

I have a problem with joystick and swiping screen. I have created swiping to rotate the camera using new input system and I have joystick created on the left bottom corner. what my problem is when I use joystick, both joystick and swiping screen functions working together. And it is not good because I don't want the swiping function response when I pressing joystick.

I have no idea.

I would like to limit the the touchable area and how can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `IsPointerOverGameObject()` ([documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.html?q=ispointerovergameobject)).

In your swipe logic, check if the pointer with the given ID is not over an **EventSystem** object before rotating the camera. Something like this:

```
if(!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) {
   // the pointer is not over any UI objects, rotate the camera
} else {
   // the pointer is over a UI object, do not rotate the camera
}
```

If needed, in the UI space that the user will use to swipe and rotate the camera you can add a transparent **Image** with the **Raycast target** set to false to ensure that `EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()` will return false.

Comment: how to fix when the touch pressing on the joystick out of the border and it begins to interact with the touch screen which causes the camera to rotate.

Comment: You can avoid that by doing the above check only on `TouchPhase.Began` ([documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.Began.html)), in case you developing on mobile, or more generally `OnPointerDown` ([documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable.OnPointerDown.html)). You can then store the value returned by `IsPointerOverGameObject()` in a boolean and use that to check if you need to rotate the camera or not for the whole time the user is touching/pressing down.

Comment: How can i do it. I'm currently using new input system.

Comment: I've got a crazy idea, I'm going to use floating joystick instead of touch thing and new input system.